# Python/Pandas - format of "to_csv", padding and alignment

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

If I write with Pandas `data.to_csv(..., sep=' ')` I get this `*.txt` output format:

```
10065424 302.835 -14.379 277.392
10065425 302.821 65.358 276.619
10065426 302.879 65.358 281.618
10065427 302.906 -14.379 282.391
10065428 302.905 10.767 282.391
10065429 302.839 60.992 277.320
10065430 302.835 -19.408 277.392
```

Any idea how to do a padding and alignment to the right by 8 characters for each value of each column?

Tried different things like for example: `'{:>8}'.format(...)`

Comment: Are you looking to give each entry the same width, or add 8 spaces before each entry?

Answer (score 4):

More readable and probably much faster than manually processing each line in vanilla Python: write the fixed-width representation (`__repr__()`) of the DataFrame to a file.

```
# Without this, the middle of long DFs will display as '...'
pd.options.display.max_rows = len(df)

with open('test-file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.__repr__())
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would read the data back into python line by line and pad it manually.  Something like:

`with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
    in_lines = f.readlines()
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    eight_spaces = '        '
    for line in in_lines:
        split_line = line.split()
        out_line = eight_spaces.join(split_line)
        f.write(out_line + '\n')`